# How to a make an object call its constructor in an array?

Tags: java

```
public static void createPlayers(int x) {
    System.out.println("How many players/AI will be playing this game?");
    numOfPlayers = scan.nextInt();
    HoldEmTurns players[] = new HoldEmTurns[x];
    for (int c = 0; c < x; c++) {
        players[c] = new HoldEmTurns(players[c].getHuman(),players[c].getName());
    }
```

}

Whenever I run this, it runs these two lines and then terminates:

```
System.out.println("How many players/AI will be playing this game?");
    numOfPlayers = scan.nextInt();
```

So pretty much how to a make an object call its constructor in an array?

Comment: This line makes no sense: `players[c] = new HoldEmTurns(players[c].getHuman(),players[c].getName());` You want to initialize `players[c]`, but you also call methods on `players[c]` and pretend it has been initialized already.

Comment: @Tom Exactly that is my issue, I want it to create that object then it gets initialized once the constructor is called.

Comment: @JackB What do you expect to be returned by `getHuman()` and `getName()` if the object does not exist yet? A newly initialized (reference) array has all elements set to `null`…

Comment: You obviously can't get information about that object if it doesn't exist yet. So what "name" do you expect here? Why should it come from?

Comment: "it runs these two lines and then terminates:" — Instead of just terminating, I'd expect it to throw a `NullPointerException`…

Comment: `public HoldEmTurns(boolean isHuman, String playerName){
  System.out.println("Is this player human?");
  human = scan.nextBoolean();
  System.out.println("What is the name of this player?");
  name = scan.next();
 }
 
 public static void createPlayers(int x) {
  System.out.println("How many players/AI will be playing this game?");
  numOfPlayers = scan.nextInt();
  HoldEmTurns players[] = new HoldEmTurns[x];
  for (int c = 0; c < x; c++) {
   players[c] = new HoldEmTurns(players[c].getHuman(),players[c].getName());
  }
  
 }`

Comment: `public String getName() {
  return name;
 }
public boolean getHuman() {
  return human;
 }
public static int playerNum() {
  return numOfPlayers;
 }`

Comment: I want the object to be created then ask what the parameters are

Comment: @JackB then remove the arguments from that constructor. It doesn't do anything with them anyway. But it's not a good idea to put code asking for information in your constructor. Put that outside the class, and construct the object once you know what iinformation it must have.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this *example*:

Suppose you have a class **`SomeClass`** and it contains two fields a **`String`** & an **`int`**

```
public class SomeClass {

    String aString;
    int someInteger;
    ...............
}
```

You can create a constructor to be used every time an **`Instance`** of type **`SomeClass`** is created. So each **`Object`** of type **`SomeClass`** you create, you have to initialize it with the arguments. Eventually, it will exist, and its fields now have values instead of **`null`**:

```
public SomeClass(String aString, int someInteger){
    this.aString = aString;
    this.someInteger = someInteger;
}
```

Furthermore, you can create another constructor that accepts no arguments/parameters (that's called Overloading). As a result, you can either create an instance of this class and initialize its attributes or create empty object that its attributes not yet initialized (*so you assign them values via setters later after creating the object*):

```
public SomeClass(){
// Empty constructor
}
```

Now Consider this setter method which can be invoked on the created object. Via the methods you can set/ get the object attributes/fields. This method for example change the **`aString`** field value:

```
public void changeTheString(String newString){
        aString = newString;
}
```

You can create other methods to manipulate the attributes of the created object, for example:

```
public void changeTheInteger(int newInteger){
    someInteger = newInteger;
}

public String getTheString(){
    return aString;
}
```

Now let's test creating an array of Objects of type **`SomeClass`**, consider this array which can have up to 3 objects of type **`SomeClass`**:

```
SomeClass array[] = new SomeClass[3];
```

Now the array is ***EMPTY***, but it *CAN* hold up to *THREE* Objects of type **`SomeClass`**. At every index (whether you're using a loop or not), you have to add the Object and **Initialize** it like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
    array[i] = new SomeClass("Some String", i); // values are for example
}
```

Now you can *invoke* the method upon the Objects created at every index, for example:

```
String theString = array[0].getTheString();
System.out.println(theString); //to print it out

// changing the String field for SomeClass Object/Instance at index 1 in the array 
array[1].changeTheString("I am changing the String");

// and so on
array[2].changeTheInteger(5);
```